# INSERT in MySQL 5.1 and 5.6 and then SELECT returns in a different order

Tags: mysql

Im trying 2 inserts into two databases on different servers. One is running MySQL 5.1 (on a NAS) and another is MySQL 5.6 (on a Ubuntu).

I do a simple

```
insert into table(pri1,pri2,value) values (1,1,1);
insert into table(pri1,pri2,value) values (1,2,1);
```

In that order.

When I do a

```
select * from table;
```

MySQL 5.6 returns

```
pri1 pri2 value
1    1     1
1    2     1
```

Which is correct because this is the order they were inserted.

When I do the same thing (INSERT in the same order and then the SELECT) MySQL 5.1 returns:

```
pri1 pri2 value
1    2     1
1    1     1
```

Basically it stores the data in reverse and then displays it in that order. Why does this happen and how can I prevent it so it shows the data correctly like it does in MySQL 5.6 ?

Thank you

Comment: If you want to force an order, use `ORDER BY`. Anything else wont ensure an ordering! The internal ordering of the tuples in a database depends on many factors. Insertion ordering is just one of them.

Comment: You can think of MySQL's decision to return the rows in the order you wanted them as pure, blind luck. In reality, it's a little more complicated than this, but, as Sirko says, the only way to guarantee the order in which rows are returned is to use an ORDER BY clause - regardless of version.

Answer (score 3):

If you need a guaranteed specific order you have to use an `ORDER BY`-clause, i.e.

```
SELECT * FROM your_table ORDER BY your_column DESC
```

Without an `ORDER BY`-clause, sometimes it may appear as if the result is in the same order as you inserted them. But this is not always the case. The order may be affected by some factors like indexes or caching.

> By default, the rows in the result set produced by a `SELECT`
>   statement are returned by the server to the client in no particular
>   order. When a query is issued, the server is free to return the rows
>   in any convenient order. This order can be affected by factors such as
>   the order in which the rows are actually stored in the table, or which
>   indexes are used to preocess the query. If it is neccessary for the
>   output rows to be returned in a specific order, iclude an `Order By`
>   clause that indicates how to sort the results.

<sup>Source: "MySQL for Developers (4.2.5 Using Order BY in SELECT statements) - Oracle 2011"</sup>

Comment: Also if you are doing `ORDER` on column that doesn't have unique value you need to `ORDER` it by 2nd column that is unique pref. unique_id, I've learned it on hard way, when I was printing 2000 invoices split to 50 invoices ordered by a customers debt, I was getting random invoices on different pages and some customers got 6 invoices and many of them didn't get any :)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that "ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE" has a odd bug with indeed inserting. The problem is that this only exists in MySQL 5.1 and not MySQL 5.6

I imagine it has to do with editing indexes...

Comment: No, it's not a bug. It's absolutely intended behaviour. You can read about that in every MySQL manual for 5.1 as well as 5.6. Sometimes it **just seems** as if MySQL respects the `INSERT` order, but it's simply coincidence even if it happens most of the time.